# Add Entity Framework to a Module

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, orchardcms

I need to connect to a remote database in one of my modules in Orchard in order to get and save data through Entity Framework.

My problem is to get the connection up and running. I get an exception when trying.

After a some google skills I think the problem is the connection string. But I don't know what to write. I have tried everything.

```
<add name="lvbb_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Services.Database.LvbbDataModel.csdl|res://*/Services.Database.LvbbDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Services.Database.LvbbDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=databaseurl;initial catalog=lvbb_db;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor(String originalPath, String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)
at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at Allvinskan.LVBBFunctions.Services.SaveDatabaseService.SaveUserModel(EditUserViewModel model) in c:\tfsOnline\Allvinskan\LVBB\X\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Allvinskan.LVBBFunctions\Services\SaveDatabaseService.cs:line 16
at Allvinskan.LVBBFunctions.Controllers.UserController.EditUser(EditUserViewModel model) in c:\tfsOnline\Allvinskan\LVBB\X\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Allvinskan.LVBBFunctions\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 64
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in this stack trace that comes from Orchard, so it's probably a pure EF configuration problem.

Comment: I actually solved it by adding the entity framework to the module. But to get all the configurations working I added the connectionstring and other webcofig's to the Orchard.Web web.config.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime ago I spent a lot of time trying to make EF work inside an Orchard module. It worked in the end. But it required some hacks and patches to Orchard core. The main problem was overlapping transactions between NHibernate and EF.
So despite the fact it is possible, I would not recommend anyone going the same route.

A possible clean workaround in such situation is to create a Web service that encapsulates all EF code, and call this service from your module. Both can run on the same machine. The service can be restricted to localhost only to avoid security issues when someone tries to access it from outside.

Comment: Have you documented the steps to change the ORM to EF?